What's the original source of this popular Krishna bhajan?
Achyutam keshavam krishna damodaram Ram narayanam, Janki vallabham'
There's also an extended hindi version, which goes something like this
'Achyutam Keshavam Krishna Damodaram
Rama naraynam Janaki vallabham
Kaun kehta hai Bhagvan aate nahi
Tum Meera ke jaise bulate nahi'
Is this mentioned in any of our scriptures? If yes, then which one?

Acyutāṣṭakam stotra by Ādi Śaṅkara

@Bingming Where exactly? What's the full strota? Any link for reference?

https://sringeri.net/stotras/vishnustotrani/achyutashtakam
